# Почему "культура и искусство" в одной фразе как равные?

Tags: словоупотребление

Искусство - это часть культуры. Культура - более общее понятие. Говорить "культура и искусство" тоже самое что "человек и ноги". Является ли это нормой?

Comment: А что не так в словосочетании «человек и ноги»? [Вот](http://litprom.ru/thread28717.html). Человек является частью природы, но выражение «человек и природа» не вызывает вопросов. То же самое с фразой «человек и вселенная».

Comment: Человек и природа идет от частного к общему. То же самое про вселенную. Ноги и человек звучит более благородно. Человек и его ноги - нет. Ноги человека было бы более уместно.

Comment: "А что не так в словосочетании «человек и ноги»"? 
хм, ничего, наверное, читаем
"... Сергей Андреич обладал сверхъестественной способностью. Сергей Андреич умел нюхать ноги. Нет, не поймите превратно, он делал это не для удовольствия, хотя, если на чистоту, какое-то удовлетворение таки получал."

Comment: Если вы написали, то как же «ничего, наверное»?

Comment: Сарказм, может быть?

Comment: А к чему тут сарказм? Это лингвистический, а не саркастический сайт, а вы ни в своём вопросе, ни в трёх ваших комментариях так и не объяснили, что вас так удивляет в приведённых вами выражениях. Почему нельзя целое и часть объединять? И что такое «культура»? Каким её определением вы пользуетесь? Не всё ведь, что относится к культуре, является искусством?

Comment: Вы правы, не все, именно поэтому я и сказал "Культура - более общее понятие." Читайте внимательней.

Comment: @1453: could you please provide the context in which you think this phrase would be inappropriate?

Comment: да просто это мещанский штамп, своего рода автоматическая идиома :> Мещанский и - культуртрегерский :>

Answer (score 4):

Эта фраза по сути является урезанием от "бытовая культура и высокое искусство". В русском языке эти понятия достаточно сильно разведены. Картины да Винчи носители языка назовут лишь искусством, но не культурой. Правда в словосочетании "наука и культура" под "культурой" уже будет пониматься и живопись, и музыка, и пр искусства)

Что касается науки, что физико-математической, что гуманитарной, то она в русском языке не является частью культуры.

Comment: Наука (любая) как раз-таки является частью культуры. И это не компетенция языка, а философская категория. Но на бытовом уровне науку, культуру и искусство почему-то разделяют, отсюда и такое словоупотребление.

Comment: @user4419802 , На современную русскую философию очень сильно повлияла методология марксизма. В этой методологии есть чёткое различие между объективной реальностью, которую изучает наука, и субъективным виденьем, воплощаемым в культуре.

Comment: Отсюда и упомянутое явление в языке, когда науку могут назвать частью культуры, только с оговорками, или в текстах, рассматривающих культуру до становления современных научных методов, т. е. до XVII.

Comment: "Картины да Винчи носители языка назовут лишь искусством, но не культурой. " - ну это смотряяя в каком именно контексте...

Comment: @Пилум слабо представляю себе подобный контекст. Культурным наследием - да, а вот именно культурой... Даже науки культурология и искусствоведение друг с другом почти не пересекаются.

Comment: Марк...  одно включает в себя другое очевидным образом, а контекст, однако, у людей разных может быть разным :> Пусть и у из лесу вышедших с возом хвороста.  Там выше сказали о  "человек и ноги" - но и так можно встретить, и ничего - мир пополам не треснет немедленно... Контекст не обязательно должен следовать строгой иерархии обобщения :>

Comment: ""Картины да Винчи носители языка назовут лишь искусством, но не культурой. " - и именно эта фраза это нонсенс... Картины да Винчи часть культуры. Мировой и итальянской. :>

Comment: "  марксизм...В этой методологии есть чёткое различие между объективной реальностью, которую изучает наука, и субъективным виденьем, воплощаемым в культуре." - и несмотря на то, что такой подход совершенно адекватен - необходимо отметить : в искусстве (а не культуре-вообще) присутствует и объективное. А не только субъективное :> И то и другое. В науке - безусловно, лишь объективное. Иначе это не наука.

Answer (score 2):

Лично я воспринимаю это (неуклюжее) выражение, как антитезу понятию "наука" (и, прежде всего, естественным наукам), так как употребляют его обыкновенно в крайне широком, неопределённом смысле, но именно естественные науки (часть культуры!) не входят в него никогда.

А что поделать? Некоторые люди прямо-таки бравируют своей невежественностью в математике, физике, химии и пр., но при этом категорически не желают признавать себя малокультурными. Будто бы не про них сказано: негеометр да не войдёт.

Answer (score 2):

Да, является нормой. Это устоявшееся выражение. Если сказать искусство, то это относителльно узкое понятие, а если культура, то это слово очень общее, к тому же имеет не один смысл. Мне кажется когда говорят "культура и искусство", то этим хотят объять не только искусство, но и другие понятия и ценности близкие к искусству, это выражение очень близко к понятию ["культурное наследие"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Comment: Вот-вот, забавная это штука - "культурное наследие". Даже по ссылке видно, что "научное наследие" к нему никаким боком не относится. Поневоле приходишь к выводу, что наука - это вообще не часть культуры, кто бы что ни говорил.